# How to print in r source stops

Tags: r

have a code that calls different codes inside it with source function. if an error occurs when running a source i would like to save the information of the error that appears but im not being able to do it. Does anyone know if this is possible? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `traceback()` after the error occurred? You can also set it in `options(error = traceback)`. I think RStudio IDE provides tracebacks by default.